# Javascript Create Custom Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler, jquery-events

I am making a Tampermonkey script, and I want to create an event listener to listen for when a video's width is changed, specifically when a video is made full-screen. This is what I have right now:

```
var htmlVideos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
function checkVidWidth() {
    for (i = 0; i < htmlVideos.length; i++) {
        if ($(htmlVideos[i]).width() != vidWidths[i]) {
            vidWidths[i] = $(htmlVideos[i]).width();
            checkVidChange(true);
            return;
        }
    }
}
setInterval(checkVidWidth, 3);
```

`vidWidths` is an array defined elsewhere of the prior widths of the video. But I don't want to use `setInterval` I want to make an event that occurs when `$(htmlVideos[i]).width()` changes.

Comment: How would the user trigger the video to go fullscreen? Is there a button? Why not just attach an event to the button? And then you can get the width of the video and see if it is bigger than before the button was clicked.

Comment: @SamEaton It is supposed to work on any website with videos, so I can't just attach an event handler to a button that makes the video fullscreen, unless you know of a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

These events already exist - there's no need to build your own logic to achieve this, and certainly not by running your code every 3ms.

You can use the `fullscreenchange` event, like this using jQuery:

```
$('video').on('fullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var videoIsFullScreen = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    if (videoIsFullScreen) {
        // video is full screen, do something...    
    }
    else {
        // video was full screen, has now been restored to default size
    }
});
```

Note that I also bound the webkit and moz variations of the event for full compatibility.

Comment: I just tried to add this to my script, but no cigar. Does this work for the latest version of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fullscreen change event to detect fullscreen :

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange',
```

And use resize evet to detect width change

```
  $('#video').resize(function() {

   });
```

**EDIT**

Resize event **CAN** be applied on elements other than the window using jquery, check this [example](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/).

Comment: my understanding of $(...).resize() was that it only worked for the window, not individual elements.